# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g, odp.net

I'm running an Oracle XE 10g in a machinem i've created a test app to test some inserts, launched it in  a diferent machine and everything worked fine.
the problem is when I installed the large app in the same machine where oracle XE is installed. When I launch the app I get this error

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException The provider is not compatible with the version 
of Oracle client  
en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
       en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()
       en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..ctor()
en Test.DB.Oracle.OracleManagerConnection.GetConnection()
```

on this line `OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection()`

I don't know how can it work from a machine and doesn't work in a different machine. The problem is in a Windows Server 2008 x64 (alredy copied the Oracle.DataAccess.dll to the .exe directory).

Comment: Do both of them have the same client (version) installed ?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: Coudn´t make it work on that machine... simply changed to other one and worked perfectly.... *Magic*

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET is a real PITA, mainly because the error message are so vague.

The following may trigger this error message:

- Your Oracle.DataAccess.dll is 32 bit and the unmanaged DLLs it finds and tries to use are 64 bit or vice versa
- It doesn't find the unmanaged DLLs at all
- The versions of the unmanaged DLLs are really different to the ones Oracle.DataAccess.dll needs

Please be aware that the process that Oracle.DataAccess.dll uses to locate the unmanaged DLLs is pretty complicated, because it is a multi-step process that takes into account environment variables, registry values etc.

Comment: So I need to use the oracle universal installer and reinstall everything on the windows server? because I can't launch that installer, the JRE crashes :( (In all the machines I've tried) the oracle.DataAccess.dll is 64 bit (I'm sure) but can i copy the unmanaged DLLs to my exe directory? will it work then? Thanks

Comment: @Santanor: The easiest solution would be to use the Oracle Instant client and distribute it directly with your application.

Comment: Alredy downloaded, should I copy all the content in my app directory? just the basic? or another one also? (My first time with this problems... :( )

Comment: Try putting all files from the archive into the same directory as your exe. Make sure you downloaded the correct version: If your application runs as a 32 bit process, use the 32 bit download. If your process runs as a 64 bit process, use the 64 bit download. If your application is compiled as "Any CPU", you will need the 32 bit download for 32 bit systems and the 64 bit download for 64 bit downloads.

Comment: Same exception, everything is compilled as AnyCPU, but I'm in a x64bit machine and i've downloaded the x64 instant client. And I HAVE TO run it in x64

Comment: Did you remove the previous installation? Running it as x64 is fine.

Comment: Also, check: http://oradim.blogspot.de/2009/09/odpnet-provider-is-not-compatible-with.html

Comment: Ok, I'll check it, cause I'm having the same error, I think that I'm gonna test my app in other machine hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

There might be another case, such as running a 64bit .net run-time against a 32bit oracle client. So can you check whether the machine which host small application runs of x64 or 32bit. If it is 32bit, then obviously the copied provider will not work on X64 windows server. In such case, you either need to download 64bit provider version Or set the target CPU flag on large  project ( in VS) to run in the 32bit run-time.

Comment: But, I can acces Oracle server from one machine with the same dlls (x64 dlls)

Comment: @Santanor: It's not about the Oracle server. It's about the client that is used to access the Oracle server.

Comment: Have instant client installed, and it's x64. but I can't execute the Oracle Universal installer cause jre crashes :(